# (Cryptic) crossword data format?

Tags: format

Is there an existing, common & open data format for storing (cryptic) crosswords on disk?

Specifically, if I were to build an application that allowed people to play crossword games, and import/export them to/from elsewhere, are there a data formats it would be good to support, or should I invent my own?